# Scala: what is the real difference between fields in a class and parameters in the constructor

Tags: scala, constructor, field

What is the difference between these two classes:

```
class Person {
  var name : String = _
  var surname: String = _
}

class Person (var name:String, var surname: String)
```

name and surname are always fields in Class Person. Equally?
I just change the way you instantiate the class Person.
Is that right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've compiled both versions of a class:

```
class PersonV0 {
  var name : String = _
  var surname: String = _
}

class PersonV1 (var name:String, var surname: String)
```

The difference is constructors:

```
public experimental.PersonV0();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #23; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return
}

public experimental.PersonV1(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   aload_1
   2:   putfield    #12; //Field name:Ljava/lang/String;
   5:   aload_0
   6:   aload_2
   7:   putfield    #16; //Field surname:Ljava/lang/String;
   10:  aload_0
   11:  invokespecial   #24; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   14:  return
}
```

Answer (score 15):

The difference between the two is, that in the second case, the fields are also parameters for the constructor. If you declare the parameters to be either `val` or `var`, they automatically become public members. If you have no `var`/`val` there and don't use the variables anywhere but in the constructor, they will not become members, if you do, they will be private members. If you would make them `case class`es, you would in the first case have no unapply for the variables.

So to answer your question: In this case you are right, you just change the way you set the values.

edit:

Tip: you can see, what the scala compiler generates, if you call the compiler with `-print`, this also works for the REPL.